# Insert a record with "find_or_create_by" inside another controller fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, record

This is my code:

class ApplicationsController < ApplicationController

```
def new
    @application = Application.new
end

def create
    @application = Application.new(application_params)
    @layout = Layout.find_or_create_by(application_id: @application.id)

    if @application.save
        redirect_to @application
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

layout belongs_to :application

When I check the Layouts table it is empty. Can you help me, please?

Comment: Are there any validations in the Layout class?

Comment: belongs_to :application
 validates :page_name, presence: true
 validates :adv_path, presence: true
 validates :start_time, presence: true
 validates :end_time, presence: true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model contains the following validations:

```
validates :adv_path, presence: true 
validates :start_time, presence: true 
validates :end_time, presence: true
```

Therefore you are not able to create a `Layout` without this values. You must do something like this (with useful values):

```
Layout.find_or_create_by(id: @application.id) do |layout|
  layout.adv_path   = 'A useful default'
  layout.start_time = 1.second.ago
  layout.end_time   = 100.year.from_now
end
```

Or rethink the need for the validators.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me to rethink my validations. I had to substitute "validates" with "validate"

Comment: What happens if you create a layout without a `adv_path` or a start and an end time? Does that work or does that cause problems at other places in the code?

Answer (score 1):

In your layout creation line, @application doesn't have an id yet. Resultantly, you pass 'nil' to the @layout's application_id which makes its validation fail. (You mentioned the layout's application presence validation in a comment).

So create the layout after @application is saved and you *should* be good to go.

```
if @application.save
  @layout = Layout.create(application_id: @application.id)
```

Comment: Yeah, the 'something else' are your other validations. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `new` method like

```
@application = Application.new(application_params)
```

it does not persist that record to db, other words it does not have id. you should use method `create` instead

```
@application = Application.create(application_params)
```

then `@application` will be persisted to db, and when you say `find_or_create_by` it will find with id, and not search for id `nil`

Comment: Even this way, it doesn't create the record... It seems to be a sample task, but I cannot accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

```
def create
  @application = Application.new(application_params)

  @layout = Layout.find_or_create_by(application_id: @application.id)  # <== that line
  if ...
    ....
  end
end
```

That line is rather misleading. @application.id is nil. So the first time, you'll create a layout record with a application_id as nil. The next time, it'll find the record with application_id: nil and use that. So it'll just create one single record and forever use it.

If you are creating a layout every time you create an application, consider doing it this way:

```
def create
    @application = Application.new(application_params)

    if @application.save
        @layout = @application.layouts.create( ... ) # assuming application has_many :layouts
        redirect_to @application
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```